# Change the cordova-nativeaudio plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am trying to change a Cordova plugin so I can change the iOS music category from javascript but I get a warning in the Cordova build log

Any idea what I is wrong with my code? The first parameter is working but the second not

```
audio.setCategory('AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient', 
                  'AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers')
```

and iOS section:

```
- (void) setCategory:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

    NSArray* arguments = command.arguments;
    NSString *category = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *options = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:category withOptions:options error:nil];


    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

I receive the following warning

> /project/koeriersapp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/NativeAudio.m:67:71:
>   warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString
>   *__strong' to parameter of type 'AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions' (aka 'enum AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions') [-Wint-conversion]
>       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:category withOptions:options error:nil];
>                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~ In module 'AVFoundation' imported from
>   /project/koeriersapp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/NativeAudio.h:11:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Headers/AVAudioSession.h:364:85:
>   note: passing argument to parameter 'options' here
>   - (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)options error:(NSError
>   **)outError NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
>                                                                                       ^

Comment: FYI, phongap is deprecated, use `cordova` name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `NSString` as `options` to:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:category withOptions:options error:nil];
```

It should be `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions` enumeration.

To solve it you can write your matcher as:

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions optionsOrig = 0;

if([options isEqualToString: @"AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers"]){
    optionsOrig = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers;
}

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: category withOptions:optionsOrig error:nil];
```

---

Ref:

```
- (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category 
    withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)options 
          error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;
```

See DOCs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory?language=objc)

Comment: So it should be a number like 0x1 and 0x2 ?

Comment: Why is this working then [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];

Comment: @JeroenWelzenVan Because `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers` is not a String but numeric

Comment: I don't understand how I can solve this, can you maybe give me an example

Comment: @JeroenWelzenVan well, I posted example in my response. At this point we are a fair way away from your original question and I gave you reason and solution. Convert String to int

Comment: @JeroenWelzenVan press on grey V on the left side of the response